# SQL how to find a multi column maximum in a group?

Tags: sql, db2

How can I write an SQL query (DB2) that will run on this  table:

```
| A | B | C | V  |
+---+---+---+----+
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | k1 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | k1 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | k2 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | k2 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | k3 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | k3 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | k3 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

and produce this result

```
+---+---+---+----+
| A | B | C | V  |
+---+---+---+----+
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | k1 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | k2 |
|   |   |   |    |
| 1 | 4 | 6 | k3 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

that is it will  select rows based on a max of a "tuple" (A,B,C) in a group:

or for two rows R1, R2 :

```
if R1.A <> R2.A  return  Row where A = Max(R1.A,R2.A)
if R2.B <> R2.B  return  Row where B = Max(R1.B,R2.B)
return  Row where C = Max(R1.C,R2.C)
```

Comment: What is a "group"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `row_number()` does what you want -- if by "group" you mean `V`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by v order by a desc, b desc, c desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```